# Why doesn't this simple jQuery ajax work?

Tags: ajax, debugging, jquery, javascript

Why doesn't this simply jQuery ajax code not load `pull.php` into the `div` with `id` of `#alert`?

```
...
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".pull_button").click(function() {
                $("#alert").load("pull.php");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="#alert"></div>
    <nav>
        <a class="pull_button">Pull Data</a>
    </nav>
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the `#` out of `<div id="#alert">`.

```
<div id="alert">     -> $('#alert')
<div class="alert">  -> $('.alert')
```